# in drupal 7, adding a form to a view produces multiple same forms because of multiple attachment , how to keep only one?form

Tags: forms, drupal, view

I am adding a comment form to a view, in fact, in this view I have 3 attachments, so when I finally added one form in the view.tpl.php through the code

```
  $comment = new stdClass;
 $comment->nid = arg(2);
 $form = drupal_get_form('comment_node_project_form', $comment);
 print render($form);
```

I can see there are 4 forms on the page, although I only need one form in that view, how to remove the additional ones ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your code only in needed view.tpl.php. Templeates listed in "Theme information" of a view configuretion. You print your form in temeplate named yout_view_id_view.tpl.php or similar. I recomend you to read documentation on drupal.org.

Comment: I think your suggestion are right.  when I look up to the 'theme information',  My view's name is  "project-deployment", so the default template is  "views-view--project-deployment.tpl.php", because I only need to make the form on the main display not the attachment, my main display's name is page, so the template is "views-view--project-deployment--page.tpl.php".                        Thank you so much for the tips